# This code is able to read a CSV file from file system but what about reading from a URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, rake, fastercsv

I wrote this rake task that enables me to read a csv file from a file on the local filesystem of my app, but how do I tweak this to make it read a file from a url?

```
desc "This class will read a csv file and display its contents on the screen"

 task :read_csv => :environment do |t, args|
 require "csv"

 csv_text = File.read('someFile.csv')
 csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers=>true)
 csv.each do |row|
   puts row
 end
end
```

Would appreciate if someone can help me with either the code or some current links. Most of the links Im finding are for previous versions of rails where FasterCSV was not part of ruby.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about using NET::HTTP?

```
desc "This class will read a csv file from url and display its contents on the screen"

  task :read_csv => :environment do |t, args|
  require "csv"
  require 'net/http'

  uri = URI('http://www.xxx.ccc.xxx.ca/~xxx/xxx.csv')
  csv_text = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
  csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers=>true)
  csv.each do |row|
    puts row
  end
end
```

That is just a little tweak for only getting it from an url and without https, but you got the idea, right?  :)

Comment: What if I wanted https? Would you happen to have any references/links for that? Thanks

Comment: Yep, if you want to use HTTPS, look at this page and scroll down to the HTTPS part: http://apidock.com/ruby/Net/HTTP

Comment: Any guidance on how to make this same call, when authentication headers and JSON data being posted are needed to fetch the CSV?

Answer (score 7):

**Open-uri** help to read remote files

```
require 'csv'
require 'open-uri'

csv_text = open('http://www.vvv.hh.yyy.ggg/~hhhh/uuuu.csv')
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers=>true)
csv.each do |row|
  puts row
end
```